# Non integrated change lists between two branches

Tags: perforce

I wanted to find the non-integrated changelists from branch1 to branch2.
When I do the following command :

p4 interchanges -t branch1 branch2 > temp.txt

I am getting the error:

"Too many rows scanned (over 500000); see 'p4 help maxscanrows'."

How I can use more restrictive wild cards in this case to get the results?
I want to see non-integrated change lists between two branches for
specific date ranges.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a date range like this:

`p4 interchanges -t branch1@2010/01/01,@2010/08/17 branch2 > temp.txt`

Comment: when I use the following command in command line it's giving output. 

p4 interchanges -t $branch1@$date1,@$date2 $branch2 > changes.txt)

But When I use this command in a perl script, I have to write like this: 

$cmd = system ("p4 interchanges -t $branch1@$date1,@$date2 $branch2 > changes.txt"); 


But the output message in commandline is some error with the following message: 
'branch1, - all revision(s) already integrated.'

The issue is because of the comma used between date1 and date2? Is it possible to use this command in a perl script?

Comment: @tom: I don't know much about Perl, but I don't see how that would make a difference.  The message "all revision(s) already integrated" isn't an error, it's just telling you that there is nothing to integrate.